# PHP login using details from two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I looking for a way to login by using details from two mysql tables.
I made a code and everything works fine but when I login it show the message that the email or password is incorrect and then login successfully.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST['Email'];  
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $checkUser1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 where theEmail  = '$email' AND thePass = '$password' ";
    $checkUser2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 where theEmail  = '$email' AND thePass = '$password' ";

    $run = mysql_query($checkUser1,$checkUser2);

    if (mysql_num_rows($run) > 0){
        $_SESSION['Email']= $email;   

        echo "<script>window.open('HomePage.php','_self')</script>";      
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('incorrect email or password  !')</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't execute two queries inside mysql_query() function, you can mix your queries to one. `select * from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.theEmail ='$email' and t1.thePass = '$pass' and t2.theEmail = '$themail' and t2.thepass = '$pass'`

Comment: Hi, my email address is `x'; DROP TABLE table1; --`

Comment: Why are you storing email and password combinations in two tables? And why are you storing the passwords in plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to skip over the fact that you:

1. Shouldn't store passwords in plain text; use bcrypt or [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/password_hash) instead.
2. Should use prepared statements (PDO / mysqli) and drop the use of deprecated `mysql_` functions; alternatively make sure to escape all user input.
3. Should only use a single table to store user credentials.

You can simply use a JOIN:

```
$checkUser = sprintf("SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 USING (theEmail)
    WHERE table1.theEmail = '%s' AND table1.thePass = '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($email),
        mysql_real_escape_string($password)
);
mysql_query($checkUser) or die("Oops!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run two queries by one single mysql_query. You need to execute `mysql_query` two times:

```
$run = mysql_query($checkUser1);
$run2 = mysql_query($checkUser2);

if (mysql_num_rows($run) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['Email']= $email;
    echo "<script>window.open('HomePage.php','_self')</script>";      
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('incorrect email or password  !')</script>";
}
```

---

But what would be better, is just executing one single query (example, you need to adapt it to your db):

```
$run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.theEmail = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."' AND table1.thePass = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."' AND table1.id = table2.id;");
```

---

Your code is also not sql-injection-safe, use `mysql_real_escape_string()`!

Comment: yes, I'm just getting sometimes tired of saying that one should use ext/mysqli or PDO…